# how to use for loop with update mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update documents of collection sale_order if `sale_order['orderId']` exists in `temp_sale_order`. If it does not exists in `temp_sale_order` then a new document will be created in `sale_order`. (upsert).

But it only creates only one document in it.
If i use `find` instead of `findOne`. it throws an error:

Error:

```
uncaught exception: can't save a DBQuery object
```

My query:

```
db.getCollection('sale_order').update(
        db.getCollection('sale_order').find({},{orderId:1}),
        db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').findOne({},{orderId:1}),{upsert:true});
```

what is the correct way? Also how to write and use a function in mongodb with above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `update` method updates only one document.
You have to set the option `"multi" : true`to update multiple documents at once.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

```
db.getCollection('sale_order').update(
        db.getCollection('sale_order').find({},{orderId:1}),
        db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').findOne({},{orderId:1}),{upsert:true, multi:true});
```

Comment: It says  `multi update only works with $ operators`. I read about it but couldn't figure out how to use it with my query.

Comment: You only have access to mongoshell to achieve this ?

Comment: i am using mongodb on local server and using robomongo for the ide. I am running this query from robomongo

Comment: robomongo uses MongoShell wich is based on a Javascript engine, so you can use javascript loops in it.
Following code will get all elements in `temp_sale_order` and will copy them in `sale_order`

db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').find({}).forEach(function(element) {
 db.getCollection('sale_order').save(element);
});

Comment: Can you tell me how to run this command from python. I am using pymongo and it is throwing me error

Comment: I never used Python driver, but you can find information here : 
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: can you help me on modifying the query you gave to update data on the basis of a key value pair?

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to give a try, search by yourself a bit, then ask a new question if there is a something that you don't understand. But come with something precise to ask :)